# Can I apply another tag to an existing image in the ECR web interface?

Tags: amazon-ecr

Using the Amazon Elastic Container Registry (ECR) web interface, can I add another tag to an existing tagged image?

The image was originally built over a year ago and many of its dependencies have been updated since then.  Trying to rebuild it locally produces a non-duplicate image.

I'd really like to avoid having to track down and pin the exact year-old (or longer) versions of dozens of dependencies to rebuild an exact duplicate image, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this using the AWS CLI. From AWS's [Retagging an image](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/image-retag.html):

> you can use the --image-tag option of the put-image command to retag an existing image. You can retag without pulling or pushing the image with Docker.

> 1. Use the batch-get-image command to get the image manifest... In this example, the manifest for an image with the tag, `latest`, in the repository, `amazonlinux`, is written to an environment variable named `MANIFEST`.

```
MANIFEST=$(aws ecr batch-get-image --repository-name amazonlinux --image-ids imageTag=latest --output json | jq --raw-output --join-output '.images[0].imageManifest')
```

> 2. Use the ... put-image command to put the image manifest to Amazon ECR with a new tag. In this example, the image is tagged as `2017.03`.

```
aws ecr put-image --repository-name amazonlinux --image-tag 2017.03 --image-manifest "$MANIFEST"
```

To be clear, this *ADDS* an additional tag to the image while leaving existing tags intact.

Comment: I was hoping to find a way using the web interface.  But this is good too.

Comment: @JohnGordon Yeah, understandable. I was hoping for an option in the web UI as well, then reverted to the CLI when I didn't find anything. Maybe someday it'll be added!

Comment: If you don't have `jq` installed, use the `--query` parameter like `--query 'images[].imageManifest'`